# How to enter multiple strings via input()

Tags: python, user-input, raw-input

When using raw_input in python, a user has to put an input and then press enter.
Is there a way for me to code something, where the code will prompt several user inputs at the same time and THEN press enter for the code to run?

For example:
instead of ...

```
>>> Name: <prompt> <enter>
>>> Age: <prompt> <enter>
>>> Gender: <prompt> <enter>
```

it'll have ...

```
>>>
Name: <prompt>
Age: <prompt>
Gender: <prompt>
<enter>
```

Comment: You may want to alter the way you ingest data entirely if you're running a script with multiple parameters or options. The [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/argparse.html) package is good for passing options to a script using command line flags. You could also leverage something like the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html?highlight=json) or [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) modules to ingest these paramters from a file.

Comment: `input` is meant to be very simple and minimal. If you want more advanced user interaction, there are many ways to create a user interface, depending on your target environment. Do you want a text terminal application, a graphical user interface or maybe a web application?

Comment: @PedroSerrano, if one of the below solutions helped, consider accepting it (green tick on left).

Answer (score 4):

No, [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) only allows one string input to be supplied.

What you can do is this:

```
name, age, gender = input('Enter Name|Age|Gender:').split('|')

# user inputs "ABC|30|M"

print(name, age, gender)
# ABC 30 M
```

Now you just rely on user not having a `|` character in their name.

Or, of course, you can ask separate questions.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to  do like this:

```
x=raw_input("Enter values: ")
a=x.split(' ')
```

And now you have the separate values in `a`.

Demonstration:

```
>>> x=raw_input("Enter values: ")
Enter values: 12 65 hello
>>> a=x.split(' ')
>>> a
['12', '65', 'hello']
```

Then you could do `age=a[0]` and so forth.

You could use the split directly like this:

```
a,b,c=raw_input("Enter values: ").split(' ')
```

One downside is that if the user does not give three values, you will get an error. If you split afterwards you can perform controls on the input first.

Note:

This method may cause problem if you want spaces in data, since space is used as a delimiter. Switch to another token in `split()` to allow spaces if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If `name` will always be letters, `age` will always be numbers and `gender` will always be letters, and they are in that order, this should work:

```
info=input("what is your name, age and gender?")
name=""
age=""
gender=""
var="n"
for i in info:
    if var=="n":
        try:
            int(i)
            var="a"
        except:
            name+=i
    if var=="a":
        try:
            int(i)
            age+=i
        except:
            var="g"
    if var=="g":
        gender+=i
print(name, age, gender)
```

It means that you won't have to worry about the user inputing a seperator.